# Do not share cookies between WebViews in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, cookies, webview, uwp

I am developing UWP app using C# and XAML. This app has several WebViews on one page.

I would like to implement something similar to this https://meetfranz.com/. So user can add services (Twitter, Whatsapp, Slack ant etc.) and work with them in one app. But one of requirements is **to have the ability to authorize with several instances of one service** e.g. several instances of Twitter by different accounts (by the way the above app has such ability, but it is not UWP app)

So common scenario is:

1. WebView#1: Navigate to some service (e.g. twitter.com/) and
   authorize
2. WebView#2: Navigate to the same url -> you already do
   not have to input login/password because cookies are shared between
   webviews inside app.

How can I authorize by different accounts in different webviews inside UWP app? I mean - in WebView#1 I authorize like user#1, in WebView#2 - like user#2.

I know how to manage cookies related to url. Like here:

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter myFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
HttpCookieManager cookieManager = myFilter.CookieManager;
HttpCookieCollection myCookieJar = cookieManager.GetCookies(serviceUrl);
foreach (HttpCookie cookie in myCookieJar)
{
    cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
}
```

But this is not suitable for me, because in this sample cookies are cleared for the url, not for the webview. If I clear cookies for the url then webview#2 again requests login/password (and that's what I need). But webview#1 too.

Comment: Please try to use [Web authentication broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker#build-the-authentication-request-uri), instead of using WebView to login account.

Comment: Thank you, Xavier. But the result of using WebAuthenticationBroker is access token which I can use to make requests to service's API (e.g. get name of logged in user). It means that I have to create UI for each service. But I want to re-use existing UI of websites.

Comment: This is the only way that I can tell you.